# Agents of Shield: looking for clues for its impact

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

It has become clear that events in the Marvel Cinematic Universe can have direct influences in Agents of Shield. I'm interested in the influence in the reverse direction. That is, I consider the following question:

**(Q)**: **Are events in AoS consequential to the MCU?**

I'm looking for events or clues on past episodes or events that have happened in the MCU or information revealed from the creators, filmmakers, showmakers to answer (Q).

So far, I personally haven't found good support to answer YES to (Q).

**p.s.** Coulson being made director seems to indicate that the impact is permanent but recent events in S02E04 (I Will Face My Enemy) suggest a possibility that Coulson may eventually be killed (by May). In the MCU, Coulson is dead so if he is killed again in AoS, his resurrection can easily be brushed over.

Answer (score 2):

As of Season 2, [AoS has introduced the 'Terrigen mists'](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2014/12/10/marvels-agents-of-shield-creators-on-the-midseason-finale-inhumans-and-skyes-identity): a Kree originated bio-technology that transforms people/ activates their latent abilities.

With the announcement of *The Inhumans* in 2018, this is a significant contribution: The Terrigen Mists are a central component and a hallowed relic of the Inhuman culture, so much so that when the crystals (pictured) were stolen by the US government the Inhumans launched a terror campaign against the US to reclaim them.

[image]

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that at this stage we have knowledge about how *Agents of SHIELD* will lead into/effect *The Inhumans*, if it does at all.

Answer (score 2):

Spoilers for both *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and season two of *Agents of SHIELD* below.

We learn in the *Agents of SHIELD* episode "The Dirty Half Dozen" that;

> It is Director Coulson that informs Maria Hill of the location of Baron von Strucker, Dr. List and Loki's Sceptre, which sets the events of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* in motion.

The next episode "Scars" shows us that;

> The Helicarrier seen in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* during the evacuation of Sokovia was supplied by Director Coulson under something known as Theta Protocol.

These two events are clear proof that in-universe, the events of *Agents of SHIELD* matter to the rest of the Marvel Cinematic Universe (out of universe, it is more than likely that the TV show is simply finding ways to make itself a part of the broader picture set by the movies).

Also in the *Agents of SHIELD* season 2 finale "S.O.S";

> We see that the faux-Terrigen Crystals created by Jiaying are dissolving in the sea, infecting fish that are swimming close by. These fish are then caught by fisherman and turned into Omega 3 Fish Oil pills. We know that if any latent Inhumans swallow these pills, their powers will be activated - potentially creating a sudden influx of powered people in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, which could form the basis for the upcoming *Captain America: Civil War* film.

Comment: Well, I had not really bothered the slightest how they came to know of Strucker's location, let alone where that Helicarrier came from and those details don't seem to have much of an implication for the story at all. Still seems debatable if they made any actual impact for the story of *Age of Ultron* or the MCU in general. Especially since the movie's story probably was written beforehand and the show then, as you say, was written to build itself into it. Something older from the TV show making an *actual* impact would be more significant, like Coulson appearing for example.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Well the story of *Age of Ultron* couldn't have happened without these details, at least in-universe, so to say that the show doesnt affect the films from an in-universe perspective is false. How about the introduction of the Inhumans?

Comment: @DrRDizzle - I would also mention that Dr. List was forced to aid Strucker directly due to actions from Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.; hence his appearance at the start of Age of Ultron.